# Convert.ToInt32 en consulta linq con join C#

Tags: c#, linq

He convertido una consulta de SQL Server a Linq y me ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

```
from TipoUsuario in ent.tipoUsuario
     join Pacientes in ent.pacientes on TipoUsuario.cod_tipoUsuario equals 
      Pacientes.cod_tipoUsuario
     join TipoDocumentos in ent.tipoDocumentos on new { Id_tipoDocumento = 
       Convert.ToInt32(Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento) } equals new { Id_tipoDocumento 
       = TipoDocumentos.id_tipoDocumento }
     join Departamentos in ent.departamentos on Pacientes.codigo_dpto equals 
       Departamentos.codigo_dpto
     join Municipios in ent.municipios on new { Departamentos.codigo_dpto, 
       Pacientes.codigo_municipio } equals new { Municipios.codigo_dpto, 
       Municipios.codigo_municipio }
     select new {
        Pacientes.nombre_paciente,
        TipoUsuario.tipoUsuario1,
        TipoDocumentos.nombre_documento,
        Pacientes.ident_paciente,
        TipoDocumentos.siglas_doc,
        Pacientes.sexo_paciente,
        Pacientes.direccion_paciente,
        Pacientes.telefono_paciente,
        Pacientes.codigo_dpto,
        Departamentos.nombre_dpto,
        Pacientes.codigo_municipio,
        Municipios.nombre_municipio,
        Pacientes.fechaNacimiento_paciente,
        Pacientes.correo_paciente,
        Pacientes.profesion_paciente,
        Pacientes.entidad_paciente,
        Pacientes.referido_paciente,
        Pacientes.estado,
        Pacientes.nombre1_paciente,
        Pacientes.nombre2_paciente,
        Pacientes.apellido1_paciente,
        Pacientes.apellido2_paciente,
        Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento
     };
```

El error que me salta es que no reconoce al compilar éste tramo de código: `Convert.ToInt32(Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento)` dice que no se puede usar `Convert.ToIn32` en una sentencia Linq.

Esta consulta Linq la creé con un programa teniendo como base la consulta de SQL Server, entonces la verdad no sé por que me quiere convertir eso a `Int32` y mucho menos se como podría quitarla del Linq, si la quito me marca error en el *join* de la línea anterior a esa.

Comment: Te recomiendo encarecidamente que crees un SP para abarcar esta funcionalidad... al realizar muchos JOINS en tu back el rendimiento puede verse afectado, ya que el backend si bien trabaja con consultas hacia la BD, no es su principal objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

No aplica esa forma en que defines el `join` de `linq`, no puedes aplicar un conversion de tipo de dato cuando defines la forma en que se relacionan las entidades

[Realizar combinaciones internas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)

Si el problema es que no coinciden los tipos de datos de las propiedades de estas entidades deberias revisar si:

- mapeaste correctamente el tipo de dato en esa propiedad `id_tipoDocumento` del paciente
- quizas debes cambiar algo en la estructura de las tablas para que el `Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento` sea numerico por definicion sin necesidad de convertir a `int`

La comparacion en el join deberia ser directa como el resto que venias definiendo usando

```
join TipoDocumentos in ent.tipoDocumentos on Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento equals TipoDocumentos.id_tipoDocumento
```

y asi queda

```
from TipoUsuario in ent.tipoUsuario
     join Pacientes in ent.pacientes on TipoUsuario.cod_tipoUsuario equals Pacientes.cod_tipoUsuario
     join TipoDocumentos in ent.tipoDocumentos on Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento equals TipoDocumentos.id_tipoDocumento
     join Departamentos in ent.departamentos on Pacientes.codigo_dpto equals Departamentos.codigo_dpto
     join Municipios in ent.municipios on new { Departamentos.codigo_dpto, Pacientes.codigo_municipio } equals new { Municipios.codigo_dpto, Municipios.codigo_municipio }

     select new {
        //propieades
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Jorge te aporto un dato nuevo, aunque Leandro es un experto, las consultas que realizas en linq, se convierten en consultas sql para ejecutarse y en sql no tienes un "Convert.To", entonces siempre dara error al querer realizar un Convert.Int32 u otro tipo de conversion en las comparaciones, si traes un dato para convertir, dicha conversion realizala antes de crear la consulta y pasas ese int a tu consulta.

```
int idTipoDocumentoPaciente = Convert.ToInt32(Pacientes.Id_tipoDocumento);
from TipoUsuario in ent.tipoUsuario
     join Pacientes in ent.pacientes on TipoUsuario.cod_tipoUsuario equals 
      Pacientes.cod_tipoUsuario
     join TipoDocumentos in ent.tipoDocumentos on new { Id_tipoDocumento = 
       idTipoDocumentoPaciente } equals new { Id_tipoDocumento 
       = TipoDocumentos.id_tipoDocumento }
     join Departamentos in ent.departamentos on Pacientes.codigo_dpto equals 
       Departamentos.codigo_dpto
     join Municipios in ent.municipios on new { Departamentos.codigo_dpto, 
       Pacientes.codigo_municipio } equals new { Municipios.codigo_dpto, 
       Municipios.codigo_municipio }
     select new {
        Pacientes.nombre_paciente,
        TipoUsuario.tipoUsuario1,
        TipoDocumentos.nombre_documento,
        Pacientes.ident_paciente,
        TipoDocumentos.siglas_doc,
        Pacientes.sexo_paciente,
        Pacientes.direccion_paciente,
        Pacientes.telefono_paciente,
        Pacientes.codigo_dpto,
        Departamentos.nombre_dpto,
        Pacientes.codigo_municipio,
        Municipios.nombre_municipio,
        Pacientes.fechaNacimiento_paciente,
        Pacientes.correo_paciente,
        Pacientes.profesion_paciente,
        Pacientes.entidad_paciente,
        Pacientes.referido_paciente,
        Pacientes.estado,
        Pacientes.nombre1_paciente,
        Pacientes.nombre2_paciente,
        Pacientes.apellido1_paciente,
        Pacientes.apellido2_paciente,
        Pacientes.id_tipoDocumento
     };
```